# Populating Blueimp carousel inks in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, blueimp

I'm using ASP.NET C# to display a catalog of items. When the user selects an item, I display the details of that item and I'd like to display one or more pictures. I tried a few methods for this and settled on the Blueimp carousel. It's working just fine if I populate the links div in the html, but I need to show different pics (from URLs in the SQL Server DB) depending on the item.

The code below works to populate the links div, but all I see is a blank space on the screen--no carousel, no images.

```
    <div id="IllustrationDiv" runat="server">
        <!-- Links div goes here -->
        <script>
            document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
                event = event || window.event
                var target = event.target || event.srcElement
                var link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target
                var options = { index: link, event: event }
                var links = this.getElementsByTagName('a')
                blueimp.Gallery(links, options)
            }
        </script>
        <!-- The Gallery as inline carousel, can be positioned anywhere on the page -->
        <div id="blueimp-gallery-carousel"
             class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-carousel"
             aria-label="image carousel">
            <div class="slides" aria-live="off"></div>
            <h3 class="title"></h3>
            <a class="prev"
               aria-controls="blueimp-gallery-carousel"
               aria-label="previous slide"></a>
            <a class="next"
               aria-controls="blueimp-gallery-carousel"
               aria-label="next slide"></a>
            <a class="play-pause"
               aria-controls="blueimp-gallery-carousel"
               aria-label="play slideshow"
               aria-pressed="false"
               role="button"></a>
            <ol class="indicator"></ol>
        </div>
        <script src="../Scripts/blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            blueimp.Gallery(document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a'), {
                container: '#blueimp-gallery-carousel',
                carousel: true
            })
        </script>
    </div>
```

```
ViewState["illustration_details_dt"] = dt;

// Open div

System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl newDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
newDiv.ID = "links"; //<---Give and ID to the div, very important!
newDiv.Attributes.Add("hidden", "hidden");

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Image newImage = new Image();
    HyperLink newHyperLink = new HyperLink();
    newHyperLink.NavigateUrl = dt.Rows[i]["universal_resource_locator"].ToString();
    newHyperLink.Target = "_blank";
    newHyperLink.Text = dt.Rows[i]["document_id"].ToString();
    newImage.ImageUrl = dt.Rows[i]["universal_resource_locator"].ToString();
    newImage.AlternateText = dt.Rows[i]["document_id"].ToString();
    newImage.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    newHyperLink.Controls.Add(newImage);  // TODO - Commented for troubleshooting
    newDiv.Controls.Add(newHyperLink);  // TODO - Commented for troubleshooting
}

IllustrationDiv.Controls.AddAt(0,newDiv);  // Add the new div to our already existing div
```

I'm looking for options. If populating the links div from codebehind isn't going to work, what would work? If populating the links div from codebehind does work, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I'm using a master page on my site with a content placeholder for the subpages. Because I'm using a ContentPlaceholderID = "MainContent", `MainContent_` is appended to each of the IDs on my page, so my blueimp script looking for `document.getElementById('links')` needed to have "MainContent_" prepended to "links". I change the script to:

```
    <script>
        document.getElementById('MainContent_links').onclick = function (event) {
            event = event || window.event
            var target = event.target || event.srcElement
            var link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target
            var options = { index: link, event: event }
            var links = this.getElementsByTagName('a')
            blueimp.Gallery(links, options)
        }
        var carouselOptions = {
            startSlideshow: true
        }
    </script>
```

The links were populating just fine, but blueimp couldn't find them. This fixed it.